# Single prompt parameter for shared parameter in sub-reports' queries

Tags: ms-access, parameters, report

I have put two sub-reports in a main report. The main report comes out fine, but the `[Enter Year]` parameter appears twice: once for each sub-report's query where it occurs. This is normal, and I can probably reduce it to one prompt by writing code.

But I think there must be a way to give a named parameter once, and the sub-report queries will pick it up and use it. I would like a non-code method to do this, since next I will do a similar collected report for many sub-reports with shared parameters.

I've tried:
1. Setting the control source for a text field on the main form to `=[Enter Year]` doesn't cause a prompt at all.
2. Setting the datasource for the main form to `SELECT * FROM <common table> WHERE year=[Enter Year]` causes a prompt and skips the ones for the sub-reports, but strangely causes the sub-report pages to be repeated infinitely.

This is for Access 2003.

**Edit:**
1. above doesn't work because I want the "prompt reuse" to be in the query. If it weren't for the parameter being used as a (standard "time period") filter I could of course just set a text field to the value of the parent.

Right now I've based the main report on a simple query that includes the prompted parameter as a column. But for some reason Access says the reference to the column (tmpYear) is "dubious"/"unequivocal" (I'm not running an English Access). Likely this is because the column in the main report query is not "finished" when the sub-report query wants it.

To me, this changes the question to: ***how to get the value of a main report text field into the queries of the sub-reports***.

**Edit 2:**
I now understand that there are two alternatives to solve this:
a) Write a global function that returns a prompted value, and use that function in the query design.
b) Keep the original query with parameters and set myQueryDef.Parameters("") to the prompted value.

***...Except b) still gives the sub-query prompts.***

(I'm sorry for making this a piecemeal question, but maybe it will match such a journey of discovery of others. If you want I could post a new short question as to why b) doesn't work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be possible (at least by my understanding of your question).

You need to put your parameter in the **query behind your main report** and make it come out as a field:

```
SELECT YearParam:[Enter Year], <<Other Fields Here>> FROM <<Table NAME>>
```

Then on the main report, place a textbox in the **Report Header** with a control source of the field name (YearParam) and name the textbox (txtYearParam, for example).

Now, on **each of the queries behind your sub-reports** (or on the report filter) make it look at the main report textbox using the following syntax:

```
Reports!ReportName.txtYearParam
```

I tested this with a very basic report with 2 sub-reports, and the parameter only appears once and filters correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this tomorrow. I have tested this, but not that particular ! and . combo.

Comment: Yes, it has to be in a query and not a query typed in as the controlsource for the report. I tried that before (see above) but it repeated the pages for each row that query returned. So I turned SELECT into SELECT TOP 1 and now it works. I had Reports!Reportname!txtYear also. Do you have a good reference on the syntax of those? Anyway, thanks a bunch - now I can do the big report. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working! :) When I tried this, I used a table for my main report containing only one record, so I didn't have the multi-page problem. Another way to solve it may be to put the subreports in your report header/footer, but obviously that depends if it suits your report layout. With regards to the syntax, [this](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2008/05/30/dot-or-bang.aspx) is good explanation.

Comment: even better: you can just write `condition = Parent!txtYearParam`. By using "Parent", you can rename the Report without breaking it.