# Single prompt parameter(Date Range) for shared parameter in sub-reports' queries in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010 and have used a sub-report in the main report. The main report comes out fine, but the date range parameter (Between [enter start date] And [enter end date]) has been asked twice, one time for the main report and another time for the sub report.

I would like to parse the parameter only once. I followed below method mentioned in one of the article, but the numbers are wrong since the sub report takes only very first date from the result and parse it to the sub report(instead of parsing both "From" and "To" values.

Please help to enter the date range just one time.

I have followed:

You need to put your parameter in the query behind your main report and make it come out as a field:

```
SELECT YearParam:[Enter Year], <<Other Fields Here>> FROM <<Table NAME>>
```

Then on the main report, place a textbox in the Report Header with a control source of the field name (YearParam) and name the textbox (txtYearParam, for example).

Now, on each of the queries behind your sub-reports (or on the report filter) make it look at the main report textbox using the following syntax:

```
Reports!ReportName.txtYearParam
```

Article [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243720/single-prompt-parameter-for-shared-parameter-in-sub-reports-queries/15251865#15251865).